# Is it possible to generate MSIL from a Powershell script?

Tags: .net, powershell, cil

Is it possible to generate CIL/MSIL from a Powershell script, similar to what happens during the compilation stage of a `C#` or `VB.NET` project?

Comment: I think the accepted answer (by the PowerShell team member who wrote the internal JIT compilation) addresses your question; a tangentially related project that may be of interest: https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/PSLambda

Comment: Thanks, that answer is what I was looking for. I'll have to check out that PSLambda project, seems interesting.